# How can I get a IFile instance from a File object in a non Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm developing a Maven plugin that will use the IClassFile but the only way that I found to create it is having an instance of IFile. How can I get a instance of IFile from a File object ?

Answer (score 2):

Without the Eclipse core, in particular the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin, there's no resource tree, no workspace, and therefore no `IFile`s to be had. `IClassFile` is part of the JDT implementation, and it, too, is not meant to be used outside of Eclipse. I am fairly sure you're not going to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the `IFile` in the resources stuff (you can navigate through the workspace to do this).

Have a look [in this documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resInt.htm?cp=2_0_10) to see what you will need to do.